# How to toggle disable/enable PrimeFaces component with p:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there some simple way to toggle disable/enable on selectOneMenu based on selectBooleanCheckbox

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="labelBox" onchange="(PF('SelectList').enable();" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="listUrgent" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selected.listUrgent}" widgetVar="SelectList" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a boolean in your bean and bind it to your `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`. Then, set an ajax listener in order to update your `p:selectOneMenu` state based on that value.

**xhtml**

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="labelBox" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selectionAllowed}">
     <p:ajax event="change" update="listUrgent" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<p:selectOneMenu id="listUrgent" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selected.listUrgent}" disabled="#{!projectsControllerCreate.selectionAllowed}">
      ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**bean (projectsControllerCreate)**

```
private boolean selectionAllowed;

public boolean isSelectionAllowed() {
     return selectionAllowed;
}

public void setSelectionAllowed(boolean selectionAllowed) {
     this.selectionAllowed = selectionAllowed;
}
```